# Loss of pointer in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

consider this:

```
var master = {
  type:"master"
};

var slave = {
  type:"slave"
};

var array = [ master, slave, slave ];
```

Now if I would want to move that over to a server, in order to save those to a DB o.th., the pointer relationship will get lost, as long as I use seralisation like JSON or XML.

For instance, how could the server script know, that `slave` and `slave` are just the same objects?

e.g. this would create three different DB row, one with "master" in column `type`, and two different rows with "slave" in column `type`.

How do you deal with it? Is ther some kind of pattern which is widely used in those situations?

Comment: But isn't unique constraints on db available for such cases? Also can't a master have multiple slaves?

Comment: `slave`s are just two equals string parts of JSON after serialization. Achieve what you want obvious impossible without providing additional data, like unique id.

Comment: "how could the server script know, that slave and slave are just the same objects?" don't blame JSON even array in JS will treat them different get a object to store them

Comment: There's no native way of doing this. You could take a look at this library though: https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/17/json-referencing-in-dojo/

Comment: Why are you adding the same slave twice? Also, why aren't you having some sort of identifier with the slaves/masters. You can always check against an ID property, and not add it to an array if it already exists.

Comment: @Rajesh A better example would have been, to not call the property `type` but `name` instead. Slave could be John or Adam. Strings do not uniquely identify the object.

Comment: @ZacharyDow What is wrong with adding one object twice to an array? Image enumeration or something. Besically the same issue comes up when you'd like to store something like this `var slave = {name: 'John'}` in `var master = {breakfast: slave, dinner: slave}`.

Comment: @Chris, name cannot be unique. There can be multiple people with same values. To uniquely identify an entity, i would suggest use db instead of js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there is an easy way to accomplish what you want. I would consider doing the following:

- Have a "get or create" method manage whether to create a new record for the `object` column upon saving, and add a unique constraint on `object.type` or on `("array", "object.type")` depending on your use case.
- Use a library based on [RFC-6901](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901), such as [json-pointer](https://github.com/manuelstofer/json-pointer) to accomplish the following:

  ```
    //on the client
    var obj = {};
    pointer.set(obj, '/example/bla', 'hello');

    //on the server
    var obj = {
        example: {
            bla: 'hello'
        }
    };

    pointer.get(obj, '/example/bla');
  ```

Comment: Need some time to dig into RFC-6901. Are pointer considered there?

Comment: RFC-6901 is a standard for preserving pointer information in JSON.